# Java Spark CSV: how to insert CSV cols in the right order?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to read a big CSV file and insert it into a Cassandra database with Spark data Frame.

It does work, but it doesn't insert thing in right order

On my CSV file, the fields are like :
*name, city, firstname, country*

But when I create my cassandra table, the colums are put in alphabetic order, :

*city, country, firstname, name*

Here's what I've done so far

```
    DataFrame df = sqlContext
                        .read()
                        .format("csv")
                        .option("delimiter", ";")
                        .option("header", "true");
                        .load("file:///home/2.csv");
df.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("myTable");
```

But city is in column name, country in column city and so on...

What should I do ?

Thank you !

Edit: example of CSV File

```
"name";"city";"firstname";"country"
"smith";"london";"john";"england"
"paul";"new york";"peter";"usa"
```

Comment: can you update some lines from your 2.csv?

Comment: of course. thanks for your help

Comment: I saw in your other post that you already got solution. so you can post the answer so that others can benefit from it too :)

Comment: Sorry, but I have no solution. I renamed the cols as "a_name", "b_city", "c_firstname", "d_country", so that the order was the one I wanted